# ruby on rails 2 radio button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Right now I'm maintaining a very old rails app. The app is written on Rails 2 .
Due to some unexpected circumstances Ill need to edit some functions of the app. Now to the problem.

I've created a radio button on my view

`<td width=300><b><font size=1><%=radio_button_tag(:subj_id,subject.id)%></td>`

My questions is **how can I bind the value of the radio button to my controller ?**

I have tried `params[:subj_id]`

then created a

`<p><%= params[:subj_id] %></p>`

to check for the value on my view. But nothing is coming out.

**Do i need to use a `form_tag` in order to submit the selected value to my controller ?**

**If so is there a way to use the radio button as a trigger for submitting the value to my controller.**

Answer (score 0):

If you have an instance variable in your controller method like so

@subject

Then you will have the value in the view like so

subject.id #and any other property on the subject object.

You would get the object either through a DB call or through your params like so

```
@subject = params["subj_id"]
```